# Monitor SSH login's via slack but hangs on SCP

Tags: bash, ssh, shell, script

I'm playing around with some slack integration so that every SSH attempt gets sent to a slack channel

The script below works perfectly for SSH attempts but the issue is that when I preform a SCP to the server the terminal session hangs.

Is there a way to allow this in the script or SSH config? And is there a way to determine between SSH or SCP?

SSH changes to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

```
ForceCommand /home/ubuntu/ssh-wrapper
```

**Session hang**

```
% Total % Received % Xferd Average Speed Time Time Time

Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    97  100     2  100    95      4    192 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   231
```

**Script**

```
#! /bin/bash

# Find the session's remote IP address
ip=`echo $SSH_CONNECTION | cut -d " " -f 1`

# Tell Slack we logged in!
curl -XPOST 'webhook goes here' -d '  
 {"text":"We have contact - Server '"$HOSTNAME"' via ssh from '"$ip"'", 
  "username":"SSH Monitor"}'

# Allow the session to run:
${SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND:-bash}

# Tell Slack we're logging out!
curl -XPOST 'webhook goes here' -d '  
 {"text":"Somebody disconnected on '"$HOSTNAME"' from '"$ip"'",
  "username":"SSH Monitor"}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Added in the below which has seemed to work :-)

```
if echo $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND|egrep -e "^scp " > /dev/null 2>&1; then
$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND
fi
```